# Is there any way to fire eloquent boot events after multi recored save with insert mehtod?

Tags: events, eloquent, laravel-5.4

When I insert multiple records why not firing the any eloquent boot method?

I inserted about 100 records at once and after the inserting remove cache some models but boot methods not firing ?

```
public static function boot(){

    parent::boot();

    static::saved(function(){
        Model1::flushCache('Model1');
        Model2::flushCache('Model2');
        ...
    });

    static::deleted(function(){
        Model1::flushCache('Model1');
        Model2::flushCache('Model2');
        ...
    });
}
```

boot method not firing so I can't remove the cache after save or delete with multi record works.

How can i fire the boot events ?

Answer (score 0):

The `saved` event is only fired when using `save()` or `create()`:

```php
(new Model1($attributes))->save();

Model1::create($attributes);
```

You can't use these methods to insert multiple models at once.

Comment: Please give feedback on the answer.